# If $0<x<1$ then find the value of:

Tags: trigonometry

If $0<x<1$ then find the value of: 
$$\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(x\cos\cot^{-1}x+\sqrt{\sin\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)}\right)$$
I couldn't get any idea. please help.

Comment: do you want the interval of values that y could take given that x takes the values (0,1). I am defining y to the expression

Comment: @mathew, I don't know. The question only says $0<x<1$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\cot^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right)$$
$$\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)=\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}}\right)$$

Therefore, The equation reduces to:

$$y=\sqrt{1+x^2}\left(x^2+\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-2x+2}}}\right)$$

Should be your final equation, I believe

Comment: You should double-check your value for $\cot^{-1}x$. There seems to be a missing radical. And your polynomial under the radical in the denominator should be degree $4$.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Right Triangles]

From the first triangle we see that

$$ \cot^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\right) $$

Therefore

$$  x\cos\cot^{-1}x=\frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$$

and after multiplying by $\sqrt{1+x^2}$ it becomes just $x^2$.

From the second triangle we see that the second term is not so nice.

$$\sin\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+1}}$$

therefore

$$\sqrt{\sin\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+1}}}$$

So we arrive at the result

$$ \sqrt{1+x^2}\left(x\cos\cot^{-1}x+\sqrt{\sin\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)}\right)=x^2+\sqrt{\frac{1+x^2}{\sqrt{(x^2-1)^2+1}}} $$

Comment: How would you solve if the last term was $[\cot^{-1} (x^2) ]-1$?

Comment: Do you mean $\sin[\cot^{-1}(x^2)]-1$?

Comment: Notice that this problem would be much easier if the second term were $\sin\left(\cot^{-1}\sqrt{x^2-1}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Let $\cot^{-1}x=y$ as $0<x<1,\dfrac\pi2>y>\dfrac\pi4$

$x=\cot y$

$\sin y=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+x^2}}\implies\cos y=\cot y\cdot\sin y=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1+x^2}}$

$0<x<1\implies-1< x^2-1<0$ if $\cot^{-1}(x^2-1)=z,\dfrac{3\pi}4>z>\dfrac\pi2$

$\implies\cot z=x^2-1,\sin z=+\dfrac1{\sqrt{1+\cot^2z}}=?$

Comment: what is the final.answer?

Comment: @Aryabhatta, Can you please complete the calculation?